# Section reload not working on specific REST request

Tags: magento2, rest-api, section

I have created my custom section which reloads when cart data are updated.
For this I have created **sections.xml** file with below code.

```
<action name="rest/*/V1/carts/*/payment-information">
    <section name="mysection" />
</action>
<action name="rest/*/V1/carts/*/shipping-information">
    <section name="mysection"/>
</action>
<action name="rest/*/V1/carts/*/totals-information">
    <section name="mysection"/>
</action>
```

Here, my section gets successfully updated when first two requests are executed. `rest/*/V1/carts/*/payment-information` and `rest/*/V1/carts/*/shipping-information`
But its not refreshing my section data on last request which is `rest/*/V1/carts/*/totals-information`

I have checked that when `rest/*/V1/carts/*/payment-information` and `rest/*/V1/carts/*/shipping-information` is called, there is a call to reload section data but when `rest/*/V1/carts/*/totals-information` is called, there is no section reload request.

How can I fire a section reload request on `rest/*/V1/carts/*/totals-information` request.?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why `rest/*/V1/carts/*/totals-information` not reload sections.xml, But I can give some way to check.

Magento sets customer related data in local storage of browser in key value pair. Each key is known as section.

To check your `mysection`, you can check local storage of your browser. If you are using chrome then you can see it under Application tab.

You cam take a look more in details at `Magento_Customer/js/customer-data.js` file (this is the module, that initializes customerData), more specifically at these strings:

```
$(document).on('ajaxComplete', function (event, xhr, settings) {
    var sections,
        redirects;

    if (settings.type.match(/post|put/i)) {
        sections = sectionConfig.getAffectedSections(settings.url);

        if (sections) {
            customerData.invalidate(sections);
            redirects = ['redirect', 'backUrl'];

            if (_.isObject(xhr.responseJSON) && !_.isEmpty(_.pick(xhr.responseJSON, redirects))) {
                return;
            }
            customerData.reload(sections, true);
        }
    }
});
```

You can also look at the end of file `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/section-‌​config.js`

```
$(document).on('submit', function (event) { 
    var sections; 
    if (event.target.method.match(/post|put/i)) { 
        sections = sectionConfig.getAffectedSections(event.target.action);
        if (sections) { 
            customerData.invalidate(sections); 
        } 
    } 
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you prince for pointing me in a direction. I'll try to debug more from here.